# Confusión sobre ciertas palabras que no están en el DRAE

Tags: palabras-raras

Estoy pensando en la palabra "ofidiofilia", que, de acuerdo a [la definición de *filia*](http://conceptodefinicion.de/filia/), es el amor o atracción por las serpientes. Al buscar esta palabra en el DRAE, me aparece que la palabra no existe. ¿Existen palabras que no están registradas en el DRAE? Y si ese es el caso, ¿cuál es el diccionario mas completo que existe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Claro, existen muchísimas palabras que no están registradas.  Además, es importante reconocer que el hecho de no figurar registradas no significa en ningún caso que dichas palabras no sean válidas y aceptables en registros formales.  En textos técnicos (tanto literarios o científicos), puede ser necesario la creación de palabras neólogas, usando elementos de otras palabras ya reconocidas o fácilmente entendibles por otros.

Por ejemplo, aunque el participio activo ya no existe como tal, el sufijo sigue siendo productivo.  Por lo tanto, solo hace falta poner en el diccionario una entrada como la siguiente:

> Extracto del *Diccionario de la Real Academia Española*
>   **-nte**. 1. suf. Forma adjetivos verbales, llamados tradicionalmente participios activos. Toma la forma -ante cuando el verbo base es de la primera conjugación, -ente o -iente, si es de la segunda o tercera. Significa 'que ejecuta la acción expresada por la base'. *Agobiante, veraneante, absorbente, dirigente, dependiente, crujiente*. Muchos de estos adjetivos suelen sustantivarse, y algunos se han lexicalizado como sustantivos y han generado, a veces, una forma femenina en -nta. *Dirigente, dependiente, dependienta*.

De ahí, el usuario del diccionario puede encontrar una palabra como *nadante*, que, a pesar de usarse quizás solo poquísimas veces en la historia de la lengua es una palabra plenamente entendible y válida, no por buscar *nadante* sino el sufijo *-nte* y viendo que se forma a base de un verbo, también la entrada *nadar*.  Y entonces tenemos

```
 nadar   -     ar     +      a     +     nte    =  nadante
-------     --------     --------     --------     --------
moverse      sufijo       vocal       que hace     que está
en agua     del inf.     temática     el verbo     nadando
```

Entonces un *gato nadante* es un gato que se encuentra nadando.  Ya que hay varios miles de verbos en el castellano, sería imposible incluir todos estos adjetivos en uno o dos tomos.  Entonces, el diccionario suele registrar solo las que se han lexicalizado como palabras no adjetivales o cuando, por un cambio semántico, no es posible determinar el significado usando la fórmula de arriba.  Lo mismo pasa con otros sufijos como *-dor* («el que hace el verbo») e *-ísimo* (superlativo sintético del adjetivo), o, la verdad, todas las flexiones de los verbos y las regulares de los otros tipos de palabras.

El caso de *-filia* es más interesante porque se forma a base no de palabras castellanas, sino a base de palabras griegas o latines.  Por eso, el diccionario prefiere no definirlo como sufijo sino como «elemento composicional»:

> Extracto del *Diccionario de la Real Academia Española*
>   **-filia.** *(Del gr. φιλία, amistad).* 1. *elem. compos.* Significa 'afición o simpatía'. *Bibliofilia, anglofilia*.

Estas palabras suelen ser de uso culto y los usuarios de ellos igualmente suelen estar familiarizados con las palabras base griegas. Pero algunas de las palabras base han pasado a uso cotidiano y, por lo tanto, la RAE lo ha visto prudente incluirlas:

> Extracto del *Diccionario de la Real Academia Española*
>   **biblio-.** *(Del gr. βιβλιο-).* 1. *elem. compos.* Significa 'libro'. *Bibliófilo, biblioteca*.

Con palabras base griegas o latines menos comunes, principalmentes creadas únicamente para un texto u otro bastante especializado y que carecen de uso general, un diccionario del castellano no sería un recurso ideal en donde incluirlas  En su vez, tenemos diccionarios griego-castellano y latín-castellano y podemos consultarlos para entender una u otra palabra base antes de juntar su significado con el del sufijo.

No obstante, a veces es posible encontrar restos o pistas de esta palabras bases en otras palabras castellanas (o castellanizadas) como es el caso de *ofidiofilia*:

> Extracto del *Diccionario de la Real Academia Española*
>   **ofidio.** *(Del gr. ὀφίδιον, dim. de ὄφις, serpiente).*
>   1. *adj. Zool.* Se dice de los reptiles que carecen de extremidades, con boca dilatable y cuerpo largo y estrecho revestido de epidermis escamosa que mudan todos los años. Algunos son venenosos; p. ej., la víbora. *U. t. c. s. m.*

Quizás debe tener al final otra anotación que diga «U. t. c. e.<sub>(lemento)</sub> c.<sub>(omposicional)</sub>*, pero el usuario del diccionario incluso en este caso puede entender la palabra.  Y si no estuviese esa entrada, en un diccionario griego-castellano seguramente encontraríamos algo que diga «ὀφίδιον: serpiente pequeño» o parecido.

Si quieres saber, por ejemplo, como decir «afición o simpatía de las montañas», podemos ir al revés, y buscar la palabra *montaña* en un diccionario castellano-griego, tomar el resultado *όρος* (oros) y formar una palabra como *orosfilia*/*orofilia* o parecido según nos suene mejor en la pronunciación (los lusofalantes, que conste, usan dicha palabra compuesta sin la *s* —*orofilia*—  en contextos senderistas y alpinistas).  Podrías usarlo en un texto sobre senderistas, y sería perfectamente aceptable, aunque no habría ninguna razón por la que el DRAE (o cualquier otro diccionario) recoja la palabra en páginas.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de si procede, pero tal vez podrías considerar también "-átil" (al contrario que "nadante", la RAE recoge "natátil", así como volátil, versátil, vibrátil, portátil, o pulsátil). Pienso que nadante, de ser recogida, significaría "que está nadando", mientras que natátil significa "que es capaz de nadar".

Comment: @BlasSoriano Para el ejemplo, quería algo que no figurase en el DRAE.  Claro, al describirlo yo como «que nada», introduje un poco de ambigüedad, porque normalmente no hace falta el progresivo a menos que haya una posible confusión.  Obviamente, había :-)  Quería hablar de un gato que alguien podría haber visto que nadaba en un tal momento, en vez de uno que sabía nadar.  He modificado mi respuesta para hacerla algo más clara (y corregir algunos errores de ortografía)

Comment: Ha quedado perfecto.